# ActiveX textbox value

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I get the value of a textbox in Word?
I know in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) this is the right syntax: `ActiveSheet.Shapes(x).Name`.

I thought in [word](/questions/tagged/word) this would be the right syntax
     `ActiveDocument.Shapes(x).Name`,
but this doesn't seems to work.

With this piece of code I also couldn't find a textbox:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
    MsgBox ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Name
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used tags (object properties -> assign a tag name) to edit the object's value. Use this syntax to change the value of a content control: 
`ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Your-Content-Control-Tag").Item(1).Range.Text = "your-preferred-value"`
Anyway, thanks Rachel Hettinger for your patience ;).

Answer (score 10):

1. To get the **value** of a **standard textbox**, use this:
   `ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text`
2. To get the **value** of **ActiveX controls (OLEobjects)**, use this syntax where `TextBox1` is the control name, use
   `ActiveDocument.TextBox1.Value`
3. To get the **name** of **ActiveX controls**, use this:
   `ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.Name`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is for a default text-box, and not for an ActiveX control text-box.
I'm now reading something about 'OLEObjects' what seems a little bit more in the right direction.

Comment: @jroeleveld I edited the answer to include the syntax for ActiveX controls.

Comment: Yes, but how do I return the control name?

Comment: @jroeleveld  See the third bullet for how to get the control name.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost right... but this only works for optionbuttons. Not for a text box.

Comment: I finally got something: with 'ActiveDocument.ContentControls(x).Range.Text' I can return the values of text boxes. I only don't know how to return the name of it.

Comment: @jroeleveld  What version of Word are you using? The code works for v2010.

Comment: v2010. If I use your code, I get only 2 objects (2 checkboxes). Not any textbox :(.

Comment: Hmph. Without seeing your particular file, it's hard to determine what is going on. My sample file has a mixture of textboxes and checkboxes on the document and the third bullet above works just fine.