# ActiveX Text Box Control Text on Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, how do I access the text value of an ActiveX text box control on an Excel worksheet?

Comment: Check out [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638022/activex-textbox-value).

Comment: Thanks chuff. Is there an Excel equivalent of ActiveDocument.TextBox1.Value?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text` to set or get the contents of an ActiveX textbox control.

If you have more than one ActiveX textbox on a page, you can use `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("boxname").Object.Text` to set or get its contents.  boxname is the name of the box in quotes ; or with no quotes, a string variable to which you have assigned the name of the textbox; or the object number of the box.

See this [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221581(v=office.11).aspx) for more information.