# VBA - Possible to create a button that links to code?

Tags: vba, excel, button

I have written the code for a program that outputs three columns of information as well as printing the file name. I typically run the program with 20 files in the folder so I don't overwhelm things with too much info, given there are over 2000 files.

Is it possible to create a button that will output the same information but just for a single file name entry? I want to be able to type the file name in, hit search, and have it search through a folder of over 2000 files to output those three columns of info for just that particular file.

Something that would look like this:
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim RowLast As Long
    Dim f As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, d As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.UpdateLinks = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2




    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)
            'print file name to Column 1

            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet


'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetUniques(hc.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the masterfile, column 3
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If

'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetUniques(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If

'(5)
            With WB
               'print TDS information
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                        'print the file name to Column 1
                        StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
                        'print TDS name from J1 cell to Column 4
                        With ws
                            .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i, 4)
                        End With
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
'(7)
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetUniques(ch As Range) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, c As Range, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then
            dict.Add v, ""
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetUniques = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have a button in a worksheet in your Excel file that will run VBA/macro?

Comment: Yes, I belive so. I'm not supremely familiar with VBA that's why the hesitatoin. But yes, that sounds accurate

Comment: Hi Taylor. Yes it is possible. http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212582/copy-range-from-one-sheet-to-another-vba To assign macro to a button add a button to your worksheet (Developer Tab -> Insert) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx right click on the button, select "assign macro" select your macro and click okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
'The directory containing the files
Const TDS_PATH = "C:\Data\TDS Search\"

Sub openFileCopyColumn()

'Clear our list
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6:D31").Clear

'Very basic input checking - you can always add more
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3") = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please enter a file to search for")
    Exit Sub
End If

'If the File we are searching for exists in the path
If Dir(TDS_PATH & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")) <> "" Then

    'Disable screen updating for performance/aesthetics
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Open the workbook we searched for (ReadOnly)
    Workbooks.Open TDS_PATH & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3"), ReadOnly:=True

    'Copy the range we are interested in
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C16").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6")

    'Close the file
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)

    'Re-enable screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Else
    'Let the user know if the file is not found
    MsgBox("File not found!")
End If
End Sub
```

**Sheet1 of the TDS Search Workbook:**

[image: TDS Search]

**Sheet1 of File Tools1.xlsx:**

[image: Tools]

**Create the button and Assign the Macro:**

[image: Button and Macro]

**Edit:**

First, decide what your "Search Cell" will be.

I chose `Range("C3")` on `Sheet("Sheet1")` arbitrarily in the example above, but yours can be any cell.

Then, search for and open it using the code above (all of which goes in the macro that is assigned to the button - see the screenshots for how to assign a macro to a button).

Instead of using the line:

```
'Copy the range we are interested in
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C16").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6")
```

If we want to run a macro that is stored in the newly opened workbook, we can use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Application.Run "MacroName"
```

There's some more info here:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/51660-calling-macro-another-workbook.html

Comment: So I assign the code I have written to the button and the code you have typed up above to the...textbox insert?

Comment: If you want the TDS Search button to open one file, then you would want to use something like the example I provided. If you would like the TDS Search button to run your code, you might want to add something to your code that checks to see if the File: field is blank (If they don't enter a file and click your button, it runs your code - if they enter a file and click the button, you do a search for that file.) Is that what you're wondering? You can also add a second button if there are two distinct functions that you want to be able to run.

Comment: My code currently opens every file in a folder (one by one), prints important info to columns 2, 3, and 4 and then prints the name of that specific file to column 1. I would like it so that I can type the file name into a textbox and it would search through the folder to open that specific file, and print the important info for just that file. I hope that I explained it better that time. Does that make sense? @user1274820

Comment: Yes, just replace your loop and code that goes through each file with a simple `Workbooks.Open PathName & FileName` that only opens that single file, and then copy that data as you do in your original code. You can add your code to copy the necessary data between the Workbooks.Open and Workbooks.Close lines of code in the example I gave. I can't offer much more help without seeing the code you already have.

Comment: I have updated the original question by adding my code and providing a better picture of what I'm looking to do... I'm not sure how I would create a button to attach a code to search for a file (and then perform a macro on that file) given what is typed into a textbox. Can you help me figure it out? @user1274820

Comment: Hi again Taylor, the example I provided does this. It opens the workbook, copies some data from it to the "searching" worksheet, and then closes it. The "search" for file is a simple `Dir(Path & FileName)` command. This will return the name of the file if found or a blank string if not. If it is found, you open it using `Workbooks.Open(Path & FileName).` Once it is open, you can reference it using `ActiveWorkbook` and you can access cells by using `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere").Range("RangeHere")`. I'm not sure what other information you need.

Comment: If you need to run a macro that is stored in the open workbook, you can use `Application.Run`. `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(File)` Then: `wb.Application.Run "MacroName"`

Comment: Okay great! Would I create a textbox button and then a search button and input that  `Application. Run` `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(File)` `wb.Application.Run "MacroName"` code into...the code for the search button?

Comment: Okay wonderful I will try that out! Is it possible that instead of deciding on a Search Cell, I could insert a textbox (activex control) and make that my "search cell"? @user1274820

Comment: Yes: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/text-box.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628997/activex-text-box-control-text-on-excel-worksheet

Comment: That worked very well, thank you! Okay so this is my code now... it will print out the "File not found!" msgbox but it is not running the macro.. do you know what I am doing wrong? @user1274820 
http://pastie.org/10229690

Comment: Use `TextBox1.Text` instead of just `TextBox1`. A few places to change: `If TextBox1 = "" Then` and `If Dir(TDS_PATH & TextBox1) <> "" Then` should be `If TextBox1.Text = "" Then` and `If Dir(TDS_PATH & TextBox1.Text) <> "" Then`

Comment: You can make sure you're getting the value correctly by using MsgBox(TextBox1.Text) - make sure it is correct

Comment: So when I was stepping through my code it goes to the line If Dir(TDS_PATH & TextBox1.Text) <> "" Then and skips right to the else. Clearly that means it thinks the text box is empty when it is not, right? Do you know what I'm doing wrong here?  
http://pastie.org/10229718 @user1274820

Comment: Your code looks okay - make sure you have the path correct - it needs to include the Entire Path & the Name of the file. Again, your code looks correct - you need to make sure the extension is also in your input.

Comment: This path `C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\` needs to include the name of the file? What I am trying to do is search through that folder "progress" for the file name that I type into the text box and have it run open the file and run my macro on it (or I can just retype the macro I'd like to execute into that search button code

Comment: No, just the path should be in that variable. Your text box should ONLY CONTAIN the name of the file you are searching for. I notice in your code you use `TextBox1.Text = "Enter File Name Here"` and in your screenshot, it looks like you are adding the file name under that line. If your text box has anything else in it, it will get added to the path, so you will be searching for the file `C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\Enter File Name HereTDS-12389-j.xls` which obviously doesn't exist. Add the code to `MsgBox(TDS_Path & TextBox1.Text)` so you can see which file it is looking for.

Comment: Yes I have been troubleshooting and found that error. My problem now is trying to alter the working macro I had to tailor it for this specific textbox task. Since it is basically a new question, I have posted it here to keep everything cleaner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716302/vba-troubleshooting-code-for-macro-and-textbox @user1274820