# VBA to manipulate (multiline) property of several ActiveX Text Boxes?

Tags: vba, textbox, activex, ms-word

I have been given a Word document with many ActiveX text boxes that I need to paste info or type info into; each of these text boxes unfortunately has its Multiline property set to False.

Is there a way to write a macro to manipulate this property on every text box within my document (added bonus if this can be done upon opening the document)?

I understand that you may need to manipulate each control individually? If so, my text boxes all have similar names i.e. `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, so it would be possible to loop through them.

```
Sub Document_TextBoxes()
    'code to loop through each text box in document and set its multiline property to True?
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638022), you can do it to all ActiveX objects:

```
Sub EnableMultiline()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim i As Long, oInShp As InlineShape, sTxt As String

    For Each oInShp In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
        i = i + 1
        Err.Clear
        With oInShp.OLEFormat.Object
            sTxt = i & vbTab & .Name
            sTxt = sTxt & " [" & .MultiLine & " -> "
            .MultiLine = True
            sTxt = sTxt & .MultiLine & "]"
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then sTxt = sTxt & " <<-- FAILED"
        End With
        Debug.Print sTxt
    Next
End Sub
```

You can check the output in the Immediate window to see which have been changed. Used `On Error Resume Next` as there may be other type of ActiveX objects. After all, your goal was just to set the MultiLine property to True for all ActiveX text boxes.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. And yes, the On Error Resume Next was important as there were also checkbox objects in my document.