# Error on trying to get textbox text in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some code in VBA on Microsoft Word, I just want to save some text as a file in a specific folder.

Here's the relevant part of code (not including the rest as its all spaghetti code that doesn't even reference TextBox3 at all):

```
Dim foldername As String
foldername = TextBox3.Text
Dim Fileout As Object
Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\JaneDoe\Desktop\" & foldername & "\" & myValue & ".html", True, True)
Fileout.Write finaltext
Fileout.Close
```

This code ONLY doesn't work when it references TextBox3.Text, if I change that to "testing123" it works perfectly, but I need to use the text from TextBox3

The error I'm getting is:

```
Run-time error '424':
Object required
```

And it references this line:

```
foldername = TextBox3.Text
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, do keep in mind I'm a bit of a noob to VBA though so yeah :)

Comment: Try TextBox3.Value

Comment: @TechnoDabbler just tried, it doesn't work either

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638022/activex-textbox-value